# How do I add the user ID To authenticate a cookie in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I add the user ID TI AUTHENTICATED A cookie

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace project.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /Login/
        private DataContext db = new DataContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult index(Loginmodel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                String username = model.Username;
                User Login = db.Users.Where(m => m.Name == username).First();
                String pass = Convert.ToBase64String(new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(model.Password)));

                if (Login != null && pass == Login.Password)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "Project");
                }

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password");
            }

           return View();
        }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good code project article that explains in pretty good detail different ways to accomplish what you are trying to do. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36836/Forms-Authentication-and-Role-based-Authorization

```
if (!FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported)
{
    //If the authentication ticket is specified not to use cookie, set it in the Uri
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(encrypetedTicket, createPersistentCookie);
}
else
{
    //If the authentication ticket is specified to use a cookie, wrap it within a cookie.
    //The default cookie name is .ASPXAUTH if not specified 
    //in the <forms> element in web.config
    HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypetedTicket);

    //Set the cookie's expiration time to the tickets expiration time
    if(ticket.IsPersistent)
        authCookie.Expires =ticket.Expiration ;

    ////Set the cookie in the Response
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
}
```

Comment: do it put this in the login controller? my code not recognized encryption ticket.

Comment: Sorry I did not detail it. The Ticket comes from FormsAuthenticationTicket formsTicket =new FormsAuthenticationTicket(...). When you ask the ticket back the tickets.userdata will be whatever you specified when it was created. The encrypted piece can be done using:  string encrypetedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);